# What cryptographic algorithms should I use to encrypt data using private key and decrypt data using public key?

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, private-key, public-key

On RSA cryptographic algorithm, the private key is used to decrypt and public key is used to encrypt data. however I'd like an algorithm to:

1. Generate private key based on specific data so we can recover it
   later
2. Generate public key based on private key
3. Encrypt data using private key
4. Decrypt data using public key

What algorithms should I use and is there a java implementation for this?

Comment: As it stands your question is inviting opinions and seeking recommendations. Both are reasons for closing your question. Can you reframe it to ask about a specific problem you are facing rather than just asking for general advice and opinions?

Comment: You should the question about algorithms on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ ... where real crypto experts are more likely to see it.  (But I suspect that they answer will be what @Henry said.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is probably a bad idea unless your seed data has at least as much entropy as the private key. But then, it is equally difficult to store/remember than the private key itself.

Are you sure you are looking for encryption? Your steps 3 and 4 look more like you actually want a signature.

Comment: I need a way for recovering private key. I think it will be good idea to use seed data. Actually in step 3 and 4 I don't know what's difference between encryption and signature

Comment: I would also suggest using signature. 
From what I understand you want:
- Only you can create these encrypted strings.
- Anyone in the possession of the public key can read them.

So just encrypt with a symmetric then sign or something.

Comment: The problem with step1 is when the seed data is for example just a short password, the derived private key is just as easy to determine than this password. You must not assume that the derivation algorithm remains secret.